# floating multiple elements left

Tags: css-float

I have 8 divs and I have them all floating left because I'd like them to all be in the same row and overflow out of their container.  For some reason they're in pairs, I'm not really sure why.  Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wp9jB/

here is the code:

```
.standard_containers {
width:275px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-bottom:15px;
float:left;
margin-left:7px;
margin-right:7px;
}

<div style="width:690px;border:1px solid red;position:relative;">


<div class="standard_containers shadow gradient_2">

<p class="head_med_blue">Physical Thearpy Protocols</p>

</div>

<div class="standard_containers shadow gradient_2">

<p class="head_med_blue">Physical Thearpy Protocols</p>

</div>



<div class="standard_containers shadow gradient_2">

<p class="head_med_blue">Physical Thearpy Protocols</p>

</div>

<div class="standard_containers shadow gradient_2">

<p class="head_med_blue">Physical Thearpy Protocols</p>

</div>



<div class="standard_containers shadow gradient_2">

<p class="head_med_blue">Physical Thearpy Protocols</p>

</div>

<div class="standard_containers shadow gradient_2">

<p class="head_med_blue">Physical Thearpy Protocols</p>

</div>



<div class="standard_containers shadow gradient_2">

<p class="head_med_blue">Physical Thearpy Protocols</p>

</div>

<div class="standard_containers shadow gradient_2">

<p class="head_med_blue">Physical Thearpy Protocols</p>

</div>


<br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in pairs because your `<div>` has a width of 690px. Set it to 320px for all items in one "column" - to 2500px for all items in one "row".

If the div *must* have width of 690px, `<div style="width:320px;border:1px solid red;margin-right:370px;">`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all 8 elements to fit into that div all on the same line, then you are going to have to decrease the size of the .standard_container class

```
<style type="text/css">
   .standard_containers {
        width:60px;
        padding:15px 6px;
        float:left;
        margin:0 7px;
    } 
</style>
```

I used short hand, instead of having padding-top, padding-bottom, margin-top, etc, the first number is top & bottom, and the second number is right & left.